# Get url params for form submit REACT { http://localhost:3000/shop/sidebar/list?cat=&q=black }

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, query-string

I need help to get URL params from form submit

http://localhost:3000/shop/sidebar/list?cat=&q=black

I need to get value of q

I know the the way

```
using onSubmit={ onSubmitHandler}
```

but I need a different way

```
<form action={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/shop/sidebar/list`} method="GET">



<Route exact
          path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/shop/sidebar/:grid`}
          component={Sidebar}
   />
```

When I use

```
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
```

and do

```
const query = useParams().grid
console.log(query)
```

I see only list but I need a value of q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
```

using router dom do this

```
  let query= new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
  let value = query.get("q");
```

or without router dom do this

```
  let query= new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  let value = query.get("q");
```